# how to exit remote pid, given node name and registered name?

Tags: erlang

I found that `erlang:exit/2` only accept pid as parameter.
Give node name and node's local registered process name, how to exit pid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

X = rpc:call(Node, erlang, whereis, [RegisteredName]) will provide you with the process id of the remote process and you can now doe exit(X, die_please) or wharever reason you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way in windows

```
start "observer:start" erl -name a@a -setcookie xxxxxxx
net_adm:ping('xxx@xxxxx').
observer:start().
```

Then you will know how to do.

Comment: I am writing "unit test" for my erlang programming. In order to test it is ok when crash happens,so I need to exit the process remotely. Because it is unit test, it is not helpful to use observer. But anyway, thank you for your attention.